# Updating Maven Project does not move from 75

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, updating

I have this problem. I have just started a new Maven project and, after adding this code:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The project is freezed on "Updating Maven Project 75", I am trying to search a solution, but no one is working. The funniest thing is I am following a course on line about Spring and it is just the first attempt to use Maven.

Tried to restart Eclipse, to delete and create a new project...

Comment: First why do you have a maven plugin as a dependency? Not correct. Remove the dependency to the maven-war-plugin.... Also it would help to post the log output? Have you tried to run on plain command line? And how you called Maven? Have you started from within Eclipse? If so try to run on plain command line...

Comment: Thank you very much! I am following an on line course on Udemy and the teacher does this (dependency + plugin) to avoid the initial error on the pom.xml file. I am new on Maven and Spring, so I do not know so much about it. Anyway, I have no output, once I add the dependency and the plugins, when I save, Eclipse stuck at 75 while upgrading the Maven project and I cannot do anything!

Comment: Editing: I am trying deleting the dependency, and for now it seems working.

Comment: Build the project for the first time outside of Eclipse (plain command line)...afterwards import it into Eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this m2e setting: Preferences > Maven > Annotation Processing > Do not automatically configure/execute annotation processing from pom.xml fixed the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

Remove the errors sowing components from all pom.xml files in your IDE. Then clean the projects. Maven must update complete now.